# Auto-detect the redirect url from the original url

Tags: redirect

is there any way to get the redirect url in PHP when all you have is the origin url?
For example:
- You create an article that has a slug of `test-redirect`.
- Inside the article editing screen you change that slug to `test-redirect-new`
If all you have is `http://example.com/test-redirect`, is there some function in which you can pass `http://example.com/test-redirect` and get back `http://example.com/test-redirect-new`? Is there any way to access it via wp_remote_get?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write your own function this way:

```
function get_old_link($url) {
        global $wpdb;

        // get only url path 
        $parse = parse_url($url);
        $path = trim($parse['path'], "/");

        // get last part as slug
        $arr = explode("/", $path);
        $slug = end($arr);

        // find post id by meta_key and meta_value
        $row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug' AND meta_value = '{$slug}'");

        if(!empty($row->post_id))
            return get_permalink($row->post_id);
}
```

Note: it is possible to make this function better. I only want to show you the direction.